# gdalwarp raster reprojection misalignment going to ESRI 102001?

Tags: raster, gdal, projection, reprojection-error

I am trying to convert 30 m spatial resolution rasters I have in WGS 84 UTM zones to ESRI 102001 using gdalwarp -tap -tr 30 30 -t_srs 'EPSG:102001' input.tif output.tif. The result is misaligned by 10 m (1/3 of a pixel) in the y-direction. I know this because I have a grid in ESRI 102001 and sample rasters that I am trying to align to (link to grid I am using: https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1527).

I have tried various methods using command line gdal, python, and qgis, but I believe these all use gdal behind the scenes to do the projection... Attached are snippets of the metadata from gdalinfo for the example raster that is aligned correctly and a raster I reprojected, which is misaligned. It appears that the only differences are in the Corner Coordinates. If you subtract the y coords for corresponding corner coordinates (example circled in red) and divide by 30, it's not an integer number and corresponds exactly with the 10 m misalignment I see. The only way I've been able to fix this is by reprojecting again by taking the y extent and shifting by 10 m in a new gdalwarp command using '-te' for target extent; however, this is obviously cumbersome and impractical for me to do for a large number of rasters.

I am looking for any suggestions, preferrably using gdal or python, to reproject the raster so that it aligns correctly... and also curious about what's causing the issue!

[image: Correct example raster info on left. Misaligned raster info on right.]